# Cannot mount adls gen2 in databricks using sas token

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am having issues mounting adls gen2 in databricks using sas token.
I am getting this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: authEndpoint" on the "dbutils.fs.mount" line

```
if not any(mount.mountPoint == mountPoint for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = f"abfss://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = mountPoint,
    extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.sas.{container_name}.{storage_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net": sasKey}
  )
```

Please how can I correctly mount adls with sas token

Comment: which Databricks runtime version you are using? SAS support is available in Databricks Runtime 7.5 and above.

Comment: @UtkarshPal-MT my runtime is 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

You ***can't mount the ADLS Filesystem using SAS key*** . The only way to ***[`mount the ADLS Gen 2 is using Service Principal and OAuth 2.0`](https://muralikarumuru.github.io/2021-06-21-databricks-mount-adls/)*** .

You ***can access the ADLS Gen 2 Storage account using Access Key*** which is mentioned in this [`blog`](https://medium.com/@mariekekortsmit/access-to-azure-data-lake-storage-gen-2-from-databricks-part-1-quick-dirty-6cd5a89aa823) by **Marieke Kortsmit**.

**A normal storage account can be mounted using SAS as shown in the below code :**
[image]

```
val storageAccount = "Cloudshellansuman"
val container = "test"
val sasKey = "<SASToken taken from the above >"
 
val mountPoint = s"/mnt/mymountpointname"
 
 
try {
  dbutils.fs.unmount(s"$mountPoint") // Use this to unmount as needed
} catch {
  case ioe: java.rmi.RemoteException => println(s"$mountPoint already unmounted")
}
 
 
val sourceString = s"wasbs://$container@$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
val confKey = s"fs.azure.sas.$container.$storageAccount.blob.core.windows.net"
 
 
 
try {
  dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = sourceString,
    mountPoint = mountPoint,
    extraConfigs = Map(confKey -> sasKey)
  )
}
catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    println(s"*** ERROR: Unable to mount $mountPoint. Run previous cells to unmount first")
}
```